# Select Date range without using jquery Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datepicker

I have used calendar for my Application.
here is reference code
[CodePen](http://codepen.io/peanav/pen/ulkof) 
I am customizing this Example to select Date range.as this is not in built date picker.I can not used **Jquery DatePicker** function as

```
 var outer = createElement('div', this.getDayClass(day));
outer.addEventListener('click', function() {
    self.getDay(this);
});



     Calendar.prototype.getDay = function(el) {
    var details, arrow;
    var dayNumber = +el.querySelectorAll('.day-number')[0].innerText || +el.querySelectorAll('.day-number')[0].textContent;
    console.log(dayNumber);
    var day = this.current.clone().date(dayNumber);

  }
```

using above Jquery code I can fetch the Calendar date on click.
but this logic is not fitting into Criteria to select date Range 
please help,

Answer (score 0):

I haven't fully tested this, but hopefully it points you into the correct direction.

above

```
Calendar.prototype.getDay = function(el) {
```

add

```
var date_range = [0,0];
```

this will create an array OUTSIDE of the function that you can access else where. It holds two values, date_range[0] will be the lower value and date_range[1] will be the higher value.

above or below this line:

```
var day = this.current.clone().date(dayNumber);
```

add

```
if(dayNumber < date_range[1]){
date_range[0]=dayNumber;
}

else{
date_range[1]=dayNumber;
}
```

Very **basic** logic to determine if the selected day is higher than the lower value or lower than the higher value. I'm sure it can be improved, but hopefully it gives you an idea.